# How to disable random popup for Bluetooth permission?

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth

I have an app that uses `always on location permissions` and `bluetooth permissions`. 
When I turn bluetooth off I randomly get an alert message (popup) saying that the app needs Bluetooth on when outside the app. Is there a way to prevent this random popup from showing or is this outside app developer control?

Comment: from which method are you showing popup ?

Comment: @lion The message is coming from outside the app not within.